# Using docker bridge network IP to access vhost in apache container

Tags: apache, networking, docker, bridge

I'd like to understand how I'm able to access a domain configured in a vhost inside a docker container by providing an entry in my local /etc/hosts file with the docker bridge network IP.

1. I use docker-compose (v2)
2. Docker network bridge IP (by default): 172.17.0.1
3. I have an apache container running on 172.19.0.10

Vhost is simple like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mywebsite.local
```

In my **local** /etc/hosts file, I have : 172.17.0.1 mywebsite.local

And it works... but how ?
Is Docker using the port to guess where to forward the traffic (from 172.17.0.1 to 172.19.0.10) ?
Can someone give me with some explanations and if possible documentation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At some point you had to start your container/docker with something like this:

```
docker run -d -p 1337:80 coreos/apache /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

`1337:80` means that `localhost:1337` in your browser gets looked up on port 80, and therefore your apache-container.

Hopefully what you had in mind?!

Also see [this](http://slopjong.de/2014/09/17/install-and-run-a-web-server-in-a-docker-container/) or [that](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-docker.html).

Comment: I'm using docker-compose, and the only thing done is using the ports directive:  

        ports:
            - 80:80

Comment: so there you go: request coming in on port 80 are sent to internal port 80 which is your apache (defined by the startup command as well as the vhost itself). so swap 1337 for 80 in my explanation and done :)

Comment: Docker will listen on all interfaces, i.e. `*:<port>` on the host, unless you specify an IP address in the port mapping.  Although `localhost:<port>` works, so will the other addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

`docker run -d --network=host <image>` or in docker compose
`network_mode: "host"`. Documentations on this can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#externallinks).

Both of these put your container on top of the host network stacks.